# When unmarshaling JSON into interface{}, it becomes not needed type, but map

Tags: json, go

When you I use `json.Unmarshal` to conctere type i get my values filled as expected.
But if i pass `interface{}` instead of struct (for more flexibility), i get `map`. How can i fix this... Or is it just antipattern, to pass interfaces.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Response struct {
    Success bool    `json:"success"`
    Data    []int64 `json:"data"`
}

func handlerWithInterface(request interface{}, response interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    var err error
    // logic with request ....
    fixture := []byte("{\"success\": true, \"data\": [20, 21, 22]}")
    
    // assingned to interface
    err = json.Unmarshal(fixture, &response)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal responses: %s", err.Error())
    }
    
    return response, nil
}

func handler(request interface{}, response Response) (interface{}, error) {
    var err error
    // logic with request ....
    fixture := []byte("{\"success\": true, \"data\": [20, 21, 22]}")
    
    err = json.Unmarshal(fixture, &response)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal responses: %s", err.Error())
    }
    
    return response, nil
}

func main() {
    req := "some request"
    resp := Response{}
    result1, err := handlerWithInterface(req, resp)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result1)
    
    result2, err := handler(req, resp)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result2)
}
```

Output:

`map[data:[20 21 22] success:true]`

`{true [20 21 22]}`

Answer (score 3):

The application passes a pointer to an `interface{}` containing a `Response` value.  The `json.Unmarshal` function traverses through pointers an interfaces to the last value that's settable, the `interface{}`. When the destination is an `interface{}`, json.Unmarshal decodes JSON objects to `map[string]interface{}`.

Fix by passing a pointer to `resp` in main.  With this change, the unmarshal function will use `resp` is the target for decoding.

```
resp := Response{}
result1, err := handlerWithInterface(req, &resp) // <-- add & on this line
```

It's not necessary to take the address of the `response` in `handlerWithInterface`.  Pass the pointer from `main` on through to the `json.Unmarshal`.

```
func handlerWithInterface(request interface{}, response interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    var err error
    // logic with request ....
    fixture := []byte("{\"success\": true, \"data\": [20, 21, 22]}")

    err = json.Unmarshal(fixture, response) // <-- remove & on this line
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal responses: %s", err.Error())
    }

    return response, nil
}
```

Comment: If I pass an interface{} wrapping a pointer, the unmarshal would work. But, why can go detect the real type of a pointer to wrapped object, but can't detect a pointer to wrapping interface{}?